# Is there a way to read the SQL query of a PreparedStatement, after it is constructed?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I work on some really old code (10 years+) and it's (probably) practically impossible to get the query that is going to be executed,
but I need to log the queries in case of an error.

I tried to read the Metadata of the statement. But that does not do the job when I try to get the exact query.

`System.out.println(preparedStatement);` is also not working because we use a really old JDBC driver, which does not implement a nice `toString()` for the prepared Statement and I am not allowed to change the driver.

```java
public void doQuery(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement st=null;
    ResultSet result=null;
    st=createStatement(conn);
    result = st.executeQuery();
    ... 
}

public abstract PreparedStatement createStatement(Connection conn) throws SQLException;
```

the `createStatement` is an abstract method with 46 (magical) implementations, which are all different.
That's what makes it really hard for me to figure out how the `Statement` is created at all.

I only want to have something like

```
String query = preparedStatement.getQueryString();
```

Comment: which JDBC driver (and DBMS product) **are** you using?

Comment: The SQL stems from you, and `getParameterMetaData` might provide the context details. The database engine might provide logging. BTW I miss `close()` on statement and result set.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name we are using ojdbc14

Comment: @JoopEggen the close statment is in the "..."

Comment: Okay. (You might also consider try-with-resources allowing exceptions and inner returns and such.)

Comment: Have you looked at [p6spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy)?

Comment: There is nothing defined in JDBC for this, nor does JDBC require (or expect) that a driver implements the `toString()` to return the prepared statement.

Comment: Are you really still using Java 1.4? That's what ojdbc14 is intended for

Answer (score 0):

Much time ago I used [p6spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy): a *proxy* for the real JDBC driver that logs real queries before passing them to the real driver.

Another solution is [datasource-proxy](https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy) that, as the name implies, proxies a DataSource, not the low-level driver.  I've never tried it.